# How can I have Dynamic Fiscal Date Range in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, fiscal

Please suggest me how can I change date range dynamically in BigQuery . For example fiscal year 2017 (4-5-4 calendar) had 371 days verses 364 days in fiscal year 2018. I don't want to change this manually every year.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by, "change date range dynamically?" Providing an example of your input and desired output would be a good start.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by creating the source view separately which cab be then joined with the main code. So that, any changes made in the source code will be reflected in the main code and can be reused in multiple programs.
This way you won't have to change the date range manually all the queries.
for more details, please refer [dynamic date range in BigQuery](https://github.com/Countants-Team/Dynamic-date-range-in-BigQuery/blob/master/README.md)